# Laravel project - When updating .vue file the changes don't show on live

Tags: laravel, vue.js

On the right it shows the source code in dev tools live from the site, the left shows the actual `.vue` file content on the server.

As you can see `nav-bar-icon20 {width:20px; height:20px;}` has been removed, yet it still shows on the site.

Tried clearing browser cache, disabled cache in dev tools, ran `php artisan cache:clear` but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Image left(source on server) and right(source from site dev tools)

[image: Image left(source on server) and right(source from site dev tools)]

Answer (score 0):

Run
`npm run watch-poll`
to update the compiled vue file, wait for it to compile and then refresh the page

Comment: Thanks Daniela, it returns "npm: command not found" when I try "npm run watch-poll"

Comment: If you have a ```package.json``` generated by the front end [scaffolding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#introduction), you should be able to run it... Try running ```npm run watch -- --watch-poll``` instead.

Comment: My host said I can't install node js :( is there another way?

Comment: Yes, compile them with node.js at your local computer and then upload the compiled assets to the hosting. You might have to correct routes and the ```ASSET_URL``` at ```config\app.php``` so that the assets point to the host base url.

Comment: To compile for production at your local machine try ```npm run production```. You can check how to compile the assets at the [Compiling Assets](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix) Laravel documentation.